Why wasn't Neo identified at the security checkpoint?
In The Matrix (1999), after the Morpheus is being captured and kept in a building secured by agents and military, Neo and Trinity make a plan to rescue him by directly attacking.
Why wasn't Neo being identified facially at the checkpoint, now that they have sufficient information and know his face, right before going through metal detection?




In 1999, computers could barely talk, let alone see. Who are "they"? The guys counting sheep? If they put up a wanted poster for this emo dude, they'd have to arrest half of Seattle.

My memory is a bit fuzzy but what I found strange is that they basically go inside that building, fight to get to a rooftop and take a helicopter there to get to Morpheus. Couldn't they skip the entire building and go straight to Morpheus using a helicopter? Or maybe I'm misremembering how it went.

@Ivo If they hadn't killed many security staff, set off the fire alarm, blown up the elevator, and thus created several massive distractions, there would probably have been much more resistance when they reached Morpheus.  (Plus, where would they have got a helicopter?)  Or, in other words: “What happened happened and couldn't have happened any other way.”

@Ivo Taking a helicopter was not part of their initial plan (Trinity had to ask Tank for flying lessons on the go, they didn't expect it). I'm not sure they even knew on which exact floor Morpheus was. Probably, the plan was just to go to the building, deal with security, blow the elevator to gain time, locate Morpheus, and extract him by any means possible. They then found an armed helicopter and decided that was the better option.

The building's lobby security station is set up so visitors:

Put their bags/briefcases onto the conveyor belts to pass through x-ray machines
Walk through the upright metal detectors
Show ID to the guards at the station and pick up their bags/briefcases

The guards check ID after the x-ray and metal detectors, but Neo and Trinity pulled out their firearms and started shooting before the guards could check their ID.
If you're wondering why the Agents or other monitoring entities did not pick up Neo and Trinity on camera as they walked up to the building and moved toward the x-ray/metal-detector units, the answer is the film has already established that Morpheus's crew and others from Zion can enter the Matrix and move about without being automatically detected.  In the movie's opening scene, Trinity is only tracked because Cipher makes a non-secure call to her. (and even then it takes some time to accomplish)  Her entry into the Matrix and presence in the hotel room were not detected by other means.
Further, if you're wondering why this building, holding the all-important Morpheus did not have watchers on the lobby cameras, the script has already described why not:
  TANK:
    Neo, this is loco! They've got Morpheus in a military
    controlled building. Even if you somehow got inside,
    those are agents holding him! Three of 'em! I want
    Morpheus back too, but what you're talking about is
    suicide!

after some back-and-forth discussion, Neo starts taking guns from racks
  TRINITY:
    Neo, no one has ever done anything like this.

  NEO:
    That's why it's going to work.

The agents prepare logical, rational security measures.  Armed soldiers control the building, two Agents are between Morpheus and the building's stairs and elevators, and one Agent is on the roof.  The security formed around Morpheus is invincible.  There is no need for extra monitoring of the sidewalk and lobby cameras because their army and Agents cannot be defeated.  Entering via the lobby makes no sense; it would be a suicidal failure.  But Neo defeats that security.
How does he defeat it?  Tank and Trinity tell us why:  Neo chooses an attack that's irrational rather than rational.
This is also how Neo defeats the Architect's plan in Reloaded (by flying to save Trinity), and how he defeats Agent Smith's viral takeover of the Matrix in Matrix Revolutions (by sacrificing himself):  He chooses irrational - human - responses to the machine-created dilemmas.

If only there was one program created to foresee human responses :)

@MatthieuM. There is... that's Matrix Resurrections.

@WernerCD: I was more thinking about the Oracle, to be fair.

Strictly speaking the decision Neo makes is rational. What matters is whether the agents understand game theory, From the agent's point of view, all possible decisions by an opponent and the likelihood of their success should be evaluated.  They either don't understand game theory or they don't really understand Neo et al's capabilities. Else they would have taken sufficient precautions.

@MatthieuM. I know that's what you meant... but the article went down the list so Resurrections was next on the list lol. And The Oracle was more on the side of the Humans (IMO) than the other machines - and She could have noticed them going for the Impenetrable Fortress but her job was to "unbalance the equation" so, honestly? she didn't notice them... she pointed them and like a good gun who didn't know why? they shot their shot as directed.

Interesting answer. Surely worth all the upvotes. I should have mentioned in my question as to "Why wasn't Neo being identified facially at the checkpoint, now that they know his face?". I'll add that to question but your answer surely makes sense about "Neo giving them surprise by being irrational."

In the original (1996) first draft, when Neo and Trinity enter the Niko Hotel lobby, they immediately attack the cops. It's not clear whether they're recognised (or not) before the violence ensues; "[Neo is carrying a duffel bag.  Trinity has a large metal suitcase.  They cut across the lobby drawing nervous glances. Dark glasses, game faces. Several plainclothes cops try to stop them.  They are met by the MUTED SPIT of a SILENCED GUN and the RAZORED WHISTLE of THROWING STARS. The cops slump down to the marbled floor while Neo and Trinity do not even break stride.]
